# Given a list of lists, how can i create another specific kind of list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

So what I exactly want to do is make a list of lists from another list of lists, but this new list takes the positions of each of the lists in the original list and makes a new one.

for example.

```
[[5,6,3],[2,0,4],[3,8,5]]
```

would become

```
[[5,2,3],[6,0,8],[3,4,5]]
```

so the new list is the 0th position's of the old listoflists and 1st position and so on.

Comment: To flip a list diagonally, the most common idiom is `list(zip(*your_list))`

Comment: i just tried this but it just gave me back the list that i already had

Answer (score 0):

You can make separate lists and then combine them to new lists.

```
list = [[5,6,3],[2,0,4],[3,8,5]]

new_list_0 = [list[i][0] for i in range(0, len(list))]
new_list_1 = [list[i][1] for i in range(0, len(list))]
new_list_2 = [list[i][2] for i in range(0, len(list))]

new_list = []

new_list.append(new_list_0)
new_list.append(new_list_1)
new_list.append(new_list_2)

print(new_list)
```

But appending new lists will be cumbersome.

`list(zip(*list))` gives list of tuples

```
list_of_numbers = [[5,6,3],[2,0,4],[3,8,5]]

new_list_of_numbers = list(zip(list_of_numbers[0], list_of_numbers[1], list_of_numbers[2]))
print(new_list_of_numbers)
```

Output:

```
[(5, 2, 3), (6, 0, 8), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: just a quick question if i wanted to make this a function because the original listoflist size can vary how could I do this